# Deleting a VBO in lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, vbo, lwjgl

Is there a way to tell opengl in lwjgl to free the data in a specific VBO or is the data freed automatically if i stop drawing that VBO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the same as any OpenGL App, the buffer is not automatically deleted, you can use GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vbo_id); to delete it. However if you exit the application the driver will clean it up automatically.